# Python UDP client on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, sockets, udp, ubuntu-20.04

I have a pair of Python scripts that communicate through UDP. The scripts work fine as-is if they are both on Windows computers.
The idea is to send data from `10.10.10.56` on a Windows machine to `10.10.10.40` on a Ubuntu one. The communication is through a WiFi router, on a static ipv4 profile.
The Python codes are as seen below:

```py
##Server
import socket 
import struct
import time

remoteIP     = "10.10.10.40"

port   = 8080
bufferSize  = 1024
 
# Create a datagram socket
UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

message1 = [0]*(62501)

cnt = 0
while(True):
    time.sleep(1/30)
    cnt += 1
    if cnt == 255:
        cnt = 0
    message1[0] = cnt

    _bytes_to_send = struct.pack("B"*len(message1), *message1)
    UDPServerSocket.sendto(_bytes_to_send, (remoteIP,port))
```

```py
##Client
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import struct
 
serverAddressPort   = ("0.0.0.0", 8080)
bufferSize          = 1024


# Create a UDP socket at client side
sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
sock.bind(serverAddressPort)
 
while True:
    print("Looping!")
    msgFromServer = sock.recvfrom(1024)[0]
    print(msgFromServer)
    
    mx = [int(x) for x in msgFromServer]
    print(mx)
    print("----------------------------")
```

The troubleshooting steps I've taken so far:

1. Check Wireshark for incoming UDP packets from `10.10.10.56`. It indeed does confirm that there are UDP packets inbound to the receiving side.
2. Check that the network profiles are assigned properly on `nmcli`. I can post any terminal output necessary for debugging purposes related to my network profiles.
3. Use a specific IP address (`10.10.10.56`) on the receiving side instead of using `""`. Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udp_client.py", line 14, in <module>
    sock.bind(serverAddressPort)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

4. Using the *exact* same scripts on a Windows install for the listener `10.10.10.40` to communicate with the sender Windows machine `10.10.10.56` (works), also make the sender `10.10.10.56` a Ubuntu machine (doesn't work).
5. Check the firewall settings with `ufw`. It is inactive.

I am afraid that this might be related to my network settings, but I have done exactly whatever I have done on the Windows side of things with Ubuntu. I don't simply understand what could be wrong considering that this does indeed work on Windows.

Finally, here's my `nmcli c show` output for the WiFi profile:

```
connection.id:                          ASUS_88
connection.uuid:                        ff935490-4b0f-447f-b303-276c5c1ed104
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.interface-name:              wlp5s0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1659449375
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   ASUS_88
802-11-wireless.mode:                   infrastructure
802-11-wireless.band:                   --
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  --
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            04:D4:C4:34:A4:88
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
802-11-wireless.powersave:              0 (default)
802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan:           0x1 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt:      wpa-psk
802-11-wireless-security.wep-tx-keyidx: 0
802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg:      --
802-11-wireless-security.proto:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:      --
802-11-wireless-security.group:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pmf:           0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-username: --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key1:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key2:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key3:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-flags: 0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-type:  unknown
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password: <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password-flags:0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wps-method:    0x0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.fils:          0 (default)
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         10.10.10.40/24
ipv4.gateway:                           255.0.0.0
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   yes
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
```

`iptables -L` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public  all  --  52.209.204.108       anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             52.209.204.108      [goto] 
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public_pre  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_post  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_post (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_pre (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public_pre  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_post  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_post (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_pre (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public  all  --  52.209.204.108       anywhere            [goto] 
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public_pre  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_post  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_post (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_pre (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Use a specific IP address (10.10.10.56) on the receiving side ... Cannot assign requested address"* - the receiving side is 10.10.10.40 according to your description - no wonder it fails to bind. `localIP = "10.10.10.40"` - this is very confusing naming of the variable. You use it as a destination in send, so it is the remote IP and not the local IP. *"Check Wireshark for incoming UDP packets"* - where did you check? On the sender or receiver side (i.e. the ubuntu system with 10.10.10.40)? *"Check the firewall settings with ufw. It is inactive."* - do `iptables -L` instead

Comment: Wireshark was running on the machine with the IP `10.10.10.40`. So it's basically a case where I *can* get the UDP packets, but Python fails to do so for some reason. I also added the `iptables -L` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this problem is related to firewall settings even though `ufw` and `iptables` were of no help in particular.
Turning off the firewall through `systemctl` by

```bash
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

seems to solve the issue for Ubuntu 20.04.
Hope this helps other people facing this issue.